# fixedpoint or fixed point or fixed-point

Tags: mathematical-writing, soft-question

I am unsure which is the right spelling (if there even is a ‘right’ spelling), but maybe native speakers can enlighten me: When should I use

- *fixed point*
- *fixed-point*
- *fixedpoint*

when I refer to the point itself, but also in composite works (“fixed point equation”, “fixed-point juggling”, “fixed-point operator”)?

And do the same rules apply to *prefixed points*?

Comment: When it is a phrasal adjective you use a hyphen. So when it modifies a noun uses a hyphen: fixed−point equation, fixed−point operator,
fixed−point theory. But, on the other hand, take a fixed point of the operator, consider the fixed point in $X$. We have found our fixed point. When the phrasal adjective ends with -ly, drop the hyphen, the -ly is your separator. So perfectly separated set... Fixedpoint is ugly (never use it).

Comment: The underlying rule here is that you only need to hyphenate noun phrases that are being used adjectivally.  Not doing so can lead to confusion - does the phrase 'fixed point theory' refer to a theory of fixed points or a fixed theory of points?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When it is a phrasal adjective you use a hyphen.

So when it modifies a noun uses a hyphen: fixed−point equation, fixed−point operator, fixed-point theory.

But, on the other hand, take a fixed point of the operator, consider the fixed point in X. We have found our fixed point.

When the phrasal adjective ends with -ly, drop the hyphen, the -ly is your separator. So perfectly separated set

... Fixedpoint is ugly (never use it).

Comment: Except that you should really do as you say and use a hyphen (fixed-point, U+002D, TeX: -), not a minus sign (fixed−point, U+2212, TeX: dollar-dollar).

Comment: So the answer originally began as follows. If $(F_1,F_2)$ is an ordered pair modifying the noun $N$, then we write $F_1-F_2$ $N$. But then I thought that was being too cute, so I cut and pasted... 

Comment: This is exactly right. Even native speakers get it wrong all too often.

Comment: @Lubin There's no such thing as right or wrong in language. If you feel native speakers get something "wrong" too often, it's either that  a significant minority speaks/writes in a way you don't like or that it's your language use that is different from the norm. This is how descriptive grammar works. Of course, if you're talking about a specific "style," there is the right way. But then, whether the writer is a native speaker doesn't matter. Anyone can adopt any standard style.

Comment: As noted above, this is very nearly correct but not quite.  (Acknowledging Yuichiro's objections, let me modify that as follows: this advice will lead to unnecessary hyphenation in certain cases, and many writers regard hyphenation as ugly and to be used sparingly.)  Ambiguity is only a problem when the adjectival phrase is a noun phrase; if it isn't, the hyphenation shouldn't be necessary.  The '-ly' exception is trying to get at this, but is really just an ugly hack that doesn't quite get at the underlying point.  'Well tempered clavier' is a nice example.

Comment: +1 for 'Fixedpoint is ugly (never use it)', though.

Comment: Agglutination can go overboard (I saw "euclideanspace" recently), but new usage is always excessive until it's inevitable.  I tried for a while to resist "semisimple", but someone studying reductive groups can only write "semi-simple" for so long.